# Error 1045 error connecting to master

Tags: mysql, centos, replication

I have a replication DB system between CentOS 7.2.1511 (Slave) and a CentOS 
6.9 (Master).
The replication failed because a 1045 connection error.
I have tried all I read in related posts, but I cannot solve this issue.

Thanks a lot for your help

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you do `mysql -u yourusername -h yourmasterserver -p` from your slave machine?

Comment: [root@servinube ~]# mysql -u root -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'servinube' (using password: YES)
[root@servinube ~]#

I don´t understand since I made GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO ‘roor’@’xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx_slave’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘passwd’;

Comment: `roor` or `root`? And you should probably remove `_slave` from the IP, since that's not a valid part of an IP address.

Comment: no....its root...that was an example...
I made:
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO ‘root’@’xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘xxxxxxxxxx’;

Comment: Try adding the same for the host `servinube`, since it's seeing that instead of the IP address.

Comment: I did that...now is showing another error:

Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work

The master has ID: 2553019
The slave has ID: 200